# How to view the original function code in DrRacket (Scheme)

Tags: scheme, racket

Is there any way to view the source code for the primitive functions implemented in Scheme / DrRacket?

I've been using Scheme for the past month for a couple of my university courses, and I was interested to know how some of the primitive functions were implemented, and how efficient they were.

For example, the map function could be implemented manually in a way such as:

```
    (define (map function items)
      (if (null? items) 
        null 
        (cons (function (first items)) (map function (rest items)))))
```

which would run in O(n). I was wondering whether the native code was implemented to be much more efficient, and if so, how.

Comment: For truly primitive functions (those implemented in C), there’s no easy way to find the implementations besides tracking them down in the C source code. For functions implemented in Racket, you can right-click them in DrRacket and click “Open Defining File” to see the module containing their implementation.

Comment: @AlexisKing Thank you!